# Ruby 'match()` method throwing an error "can't dump MatchData"

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

`Interactive ruby ready.`

```
> time = /\A(?­<hours>(0\d|1[0-9­]|2[0-3]))­:(?<minutes­>([1-5]\d|0­\d))\Z/
=> /\A(?<hours>(0\d|1[0-9]|2[0-3])):(?<minutes>([1-5]\d|0\d))\Z/

> match = time.­match '11:3­0'
=> #<TypeError: can't dump MatchData>
```

I am trying to run the code but getting error as above. What the wrong I did with the `regexp` help me to improve it.

***EDIT***

```
> time = /\A(0­\d|1[0-9­]­|2[0-3])­:­([0-5]\d)\­Z/
=> /\A(0\d|1[0-9??]|2[0-3])??:([0-5]\d)\Z/
> time.match­('11:30')
=> #<TypeError: can't dump MatchData>
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *should*  be working, and the example you linked to does work on my machine. The regex is needlessly complicated, though:

```
time = /\A(?<hours>0\d|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(?<minutes>[0-5]\d)\Z/
```

is enough.

However, it appears that somewhere in your environment, extra bytes have become embedded in the string(s), and these bytes confuse the online tester (which is working correctly). Try and copy the regex from this answer (I have removed the invisible characters) and see if it works for you now.

Comment: Yes, it does since 1.9 ? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures

Comment: @oldergod: Ah, thanks. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html appears to be outdated, then.

Comment: Please see my `EDIT` . Still I am having **ERROR**

Comment: @DoLoveSky: The traceback shows that there are spurious bytes between `3` and `0` in your input. Where does that string come from?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I got it from the [Link](http://ruby.runpaint.org/regexps) as I was going through it to learn!

Comment: I just downloaded this example, and it works fine here. Somewhere on your system, you're introducing extra bytes into the code. Perhaps a misconfigured editor? What locale are you in? Which text encoding are you using in your editor?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Okay,I am using the [online](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0)

Comment: I have accepted your answer, But eager to know if that `online interptere` is `outdated or not`?